# Azure AD SSO doesn't reply to silent sign in request

Tags: azure-active-directory

After enabling SSO for Moodle to integrate with Azure AD, when the Moodle sends a silent sign in request to Azure AD, it doesn't response to the request. And shows the following error.
AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).

What I expect is that Azure AD redirect the silent sign-in request back the service Moodle as ADFS does.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked some of the troubleshooting guides for this?

From a [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/11/07/receiving-error-aadsts50058-in-javascript-setting/) my colleague Frank Hu wrote:

> Reason for AADSTS50058 The reason that the error occurs is because a
>   silent sign in is sent to the login.microsoftonline.com endpoint,
>   however the AADSSO cookie isn't being detected. This cookie determines
>   if the user is logged in or not. The silent sign in is only meant to
>   be used if the user is already known to be logged in or has a refresh
>   token to exchange for a new access token.
>
> By checking the KMSI box the first time logging in, this will add the
>   KMSI cookie to let you refresh your access token so that users won't
>   receive this error for a longer period of time.

Other possible solutions:

> Possible Resolution #1 Proactively Check for Expiration You can
>   attempt to prevent this error from ever occurring by checking if you
>   have a valid id token. If you're ID token is not valid, you will ask
>   the user to login again. You can check if the ID Token is valid by
>   getting the token using AuthenticationContext.getCachedToken(clientID)
>   and then checking the Expiration in the JWT Token.
>
> Possible Resolution #2 Catching the Error and Asking the User to Login
>   Again To resolve this error you will need to catch this error in a
>   callback that you can pass into the acquiretoken ADAL JS function. If
>   the AADSTS50058 error occurs, you'll ask the user to login again.
>
> Possible Resolution #3 Browser Extension Cookie Blockers and Third
>   Party Cookies Disabled Some users may experience this issue due to a
>   browser extension that is blocking cookies for tracking purposes. This
>   will cause this AADSTS50058 error to occur, you will need to whitelist
>   the login.microsoftonline.com endpoint in your browser extension in
>   order to avoid receiving this error again.
>
> This error can also occur if the third party cookies have been
>   disabled in your browser. Re-enable third party cookies in your
>   browser to prevent this error from occurring.